# Can't run bash script in Azure pipeline on Windows agent with wsl

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run this inline script:

```
Pat="myPat"
B64Pat=$(echo -n "$Pat" | base64)
git -c http.https:<url>.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic $B64Pat" submodule update --init --recursive
```

And I get:

```
Generating script.
C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe --noprofile --norc -c pwd
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.

Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:

https://aka.ms/wslstore

##[error]The process 'C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

But I can run it locally, because I installed Ubuntu for my user account. I think the problem is that I need to install Ubuntu for system user. Also, I have docker agents, I think I can set one of them to be the default distribution. What do you think?

Comment: What happens if you just run a `C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe --version`? BTW, I have never used WSL, but isn't it that you have to execute a command starting with `wsl .... bash ...`  to execute an Ubuntu command from the Windows command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.

That is because the WSL installed per a specific user account, but if we run the self-hosted with other accounts or service accounts.

It will not recognize WSL installed by local users.

To solve this issue, you can re-configure the self-hosted agent with local user account or o install WSL for the user used by the agent.

You can check the current username of the Agent in **Azure DevOps-> Agent Pool -> Target Agent -> Capabilities -> USERNAME**

For example:

[image]

For interactive mode self-hosted agent:

You could use the following command to create an agent with user account.

```
.\config.cmd --unattended --url https://myaccount.visualstudio.com --auth pat --token myToken --pool default --agent myAgent --runAsAutoLogon --windowsLogonAccount myDomain\useraccount --windowsLogonPassword Password
```

For service mode self-hosted agent:

On one hand, you could create an agent with the user account(similar as interactive mode).

```
.\config.cmd --unattended --url https://myaccount.visualstudio.com --auth pat --token myToken --pool default --agent myAgent --runAsService --windowsLogonAccount myDomain\useraccount --windowsLogonPassword Password
```

On the other hand, you could navigate to **local system -> Service** and find the running agent service.

Then you could change the `logon account` as user account.

[image]

**Note:** You need to  restart your server, just restart the services is not enough.

Here is a doc about  [create agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#choose-interactive-or-service-mode).

Comment: Thanks, but could I create distribution for Administrator or make it use docker distribution?

Comment: Yes. You can create distribution for Administrator .

Comment: Could you, please, tell me how to do this?